# Text to Json in Java (list in text)

Tags: java, json

I have the following text which is returned by an API that I call:

```
{"identified_faces_names": "[\"omar\", \"elhoussinep\"]"}
```

when I pass this text to JSONParse to parse it, it give me the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" Unexpected character (o) at position 0.

Code used to parse the text to json:

```
String s = new String("{\"identified_faces_names\": \" [\"omar\",\"elhoussinep\"]\"}");
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(s);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you definitely mean to enclose `["omar", "elhoussinep"]` in quotes? Is that definitely intended to be a String value containing string quotes? Or is it intended to be an array of strings?

If `identified_faces_names` is intended to be an array of strings then the valid JSON is:

```
{
  "identified_faces_names": [
    "omar",
    "elhoussinep"
  ]
}
```

This is parseable, without error, like so:

```
String s = new String("{\"identified_faces_names\": [\"omar\",\"elhoussinep\"]}");
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(s);
```

If `identified_faces_names` is intended to be a String containing quotes you must escape the quotes inside the string. The valid JSON is:

```
{
  "identified_faces_names": "[\\\"omar\\\",\\\"elhoussinep\\\"]"
}
```

This is parseable, without error, like so:

```
String s = new String("{\"identified_faces_names\": \" [\\\"omar\\\",\\\"elhoussinep\\\"]\"}");
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(s);
```

So, in summary, I'd suggest revisiting the JSON to determine whether it is an array of strings or a string which contains quotes, if the latter then you have to escape those quotes.

FWIW, you can use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/?reformat=no) to check whether the JSON is valid. Using this you can see that your original JSON (`{"identified_faces_names": "["omar","elhoussinep"]"}`) was not valid and that the first invalid character is the `"o"` in `"omar"` and that's deemed invalid because it follows `"["` which is deemed to be a complete String.

Comment: it works, on another note, how to convert  `["omar","elhoussinep"]` to a list?

Comment: `JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(s); JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj.get("identified_faces_names");` ... ` `JSONArray` _is a_ `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this String {"identified_faces_names": [\"omar\", \"elhoussinep\"]}. It is correct and will parse.